# Creando un nuevo AVD, ¿qué CPU/ABI debería seleccionar?

Tags: android, cordova, avd, arm, intel-atom

Después de bastante tiempo, actualicé mi versión de Cordova y las diferentes herramientas de Android. Se descargaron nuevas APIs y me decidí a crear un nuevo Dispositivo Virtual de Android (*Android Virtual Device* o AVD) llegando al siguiente menú:

[image: Crear nueva máquina virtual]

Lo cierto es que nunca me había fijado mucho en el campo CPU/ABI y siempre había seleccionado el que estuviera por defecto (generalmente ARM, porque tenía entendido que estaba más extendido). Esta vez hice lo mismo, pero a la hora de arrancar el dispositivo virtual, me salió un mensaje en el que me recomendaba ejecutar un AVD basado en x86 (Intel Atom) porque era 10x más rápido.

**¿Cuáles son las ventajas/inconvenientes de elegir uno o el otro?** Y, aunque quizás se base un poco en opiniones, ¿hay alguno que sea más recomendable? (en concreto teniendo en cuenta que uso Cordova/Phonegap)

Comment: Si tienes una cpu intel, mejor seleccionar x86 ya que se usará (Intel® HAXM) Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según este [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html) (extraído también de una respuesta en stackoverflow en inglés), tenemos lo siguiente:

> Select either Intel or ARM based on your development computer's
>   processor.

Que en castellano significa:

> Selecciona Intel o ARM según el procesador que tenga la máquina que
>   utilices para el desarrollo.

Además, si ves palabras clave como Wear o TV significa que son imágenes de sistema para emular Android TV o Android Wear (Smartwatch por ejemplo).

Por otro lado, he leído alguna entrada que sugiere que se prueben todas las *system images* en las que debería funcionar tu app. Por ejemplo, si tu app es para smartphone y smartwatch, deberías probarlo en las imágenes Intel, ARM, Android Wear Intel y Android Wear ARM.

Finalmente, en el enlace que comentaba al principio de la respuesta, añade una nota cuando habla de *system images*:

> If you plan to use APIs from Google Play Services, you must use the Google APIs System Image.

Que en castellano sería algo así como:

> Si vas a utilizar las APIs de Google Play Services en tu app, se debe utilizar obligatoriamente la imagen de sistema de Goople APIs.

---

**Update**: Para que el emulador funcione mejor en máquinas con procesador Intel, existe la herramienta *Intel HAXM*, o *Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager*, que se puede instalar desde el propio *Android SDK Manager*.

Mas información [aquí](https://software.intel.com/es-es/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture) y/o [aquí](http://desarrollador-android.com/desarrollo/herramientas/herramientas-de-ayuda/acelerar-el-emulador/)

Comment: Entonces, ¿la ventaja de usar x86 es sólo que será más eficiente en mi CPU Intel?

Comment: Por lo que he podido leer a través de búsquedas de google, es que un emulador con la _system_ _image_ ARM es literalmente "**much more slower**" que la Intel x86. Igualmente también existe "software externo" que ayuda a que todavía funcione mejor. Puedes echarle un ojo a http://desarrollador-android.com/desarrollo/herramientas/herramientas-de-ayuda/acelerar-el-emulador/

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro me parece que es la única diferencia de escoger una o otra, la velocidad de emulación en CPU intel con HAXM es 10 veces superior, tambien puedes mirar otro emulador como el genymotion

Comment: +1 al Genymotion @Webserveis